# Partitioning $G$ into subsets such that each is a set of edges of a spanning tree of $G$

Tags: graph-theory, trees, set-partition

> Let $V$ be a set of all subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} $ with *exactly* $4$ elements.
>   Define graph $G=(V,E)$ as follows:
>   If $v,w\in V$ then $\{v,w\}\in E$ $\iff$ $|v\cap w|=2$
>
> Can one partition the set of edges of $G$ into subsets, such that each is a set of edges of a spanning tree of $G$?

I'm trying to understand how to look at this graphs definition, since it looks like an element of $E$ is of the form $\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{3,4,5,6\}\}$.

Comment: Quite.  $\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{3,4,5,6\}\}$ is indeed an element of $E$ for your graph.  It is a graph with $\binom{7}{4}=35$ vertices and each vertex is of degree $\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}=18$ implying there are $35\cdot 18/2=315$ edges.  Make sure you understand how I came to each of these numbers in my calculations.  How many edges would be used in a spanning tree of $G$?  If you were able to partition the set of edges as desired, what must have been true about the number of edges of $G$?

Comment: Could you explain $\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}$?

Comment: Suppose you have a vertex.  There are four numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ associated with it and three numbers not associated with it.  Without loss of generality, let us look specifically at the vertex $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  We ask how many other vertices are adjacent to it.  Any vertex adjacent to it will share two numbers from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and will have two additional numbers from $\{5,6,7\}$.  By picking which two numbers were shared and picking which two numbers were not, we arrive at the result.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a generalized Johnson graph:

- We have a $n$-element set (in this case $n=7$).
- We have $k$-element subsets (in this case $k=4$), which form the vertex set.
- We have edges whenever two $k$-element subsets have an intersection of size $r$ (in this case, $r=2$).

I draw the graph below (click for larger image):

[image: generalized Johnson graph]

We observe:

- It has $\binom{7}{4}=35$ vertices, one vertex for each $4$-element subset of $\{1,\ldots,7\}$;
- every vertex $\{a,b,c,d\}$ has degree $\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}=18$, which are precisely those with $2$ elements in common (i.e., from $\{a,b,c,d\}$) and $2$ elements not in common (i.e., from $\{1,\ldots,7\} \setminus \{a,b,c,d\}$), and
- it has $315$ edges, by the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

The question asks if this graph decomposes into spanning trees.  At this point, we can mostly throw away the graph.  We'll get the same answer to the question:

**Q**: Does any 35-vertex 315-edge graph decompose into spanning trees?